# Problems with Instantiating Next and Previous Prefab in Array (Unity 3D)

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, reverse, instantiation, destroy

I am working on a simple virtual tour app where I place a camera inside a sphere, map the sphere with a 360 photo, and click on arrow objects (sprites) to navigate forward and backward. My script below instantiates the next sphere in the array (mapped with the next 360 photo) while destroying the current sphere, simulating forward movement in the application. It seems to work OK.

```c#
public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            if (hit.collider != null)
            {
                Destroy(currentObject); 
                currentIndex++;
                currentIndex = currentIndex >= Spheres.Length ? 0 : currentIndex;
                currentObject = Instantiate(Spheres[currentIndex]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The question I have is how do I reverse the order if the array so I can click the "back" arrow to instantiate the previous prefab in the array.

I thought this was a simple as `currentIndex--;` but I cannot get it to work. Any  help is great appreciated.

[pic of virtual tour in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaRdK.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just invert the wrap-around using

```c#
currentIndex--; 
if(currentIndex < 0) currentIndex = Spheres.Length - 1;
```

You also want to do the same for the `++` way btw:

```c#
currentIndex++; 
if(currentIndex > Spheres.Length - 1) currentIndex = 0;
```

note the `- 1`! Your index should never reach `Spehres.Length` since indices are `0`-based. So the last element in an array always has `index = array.Length - 1`.

---

A slightly easier way for having a wrap-around in positive way would btw be simply

```c#
currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % Spheres.Length;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Oddly enough I am having an issue where I appear to be triggering both scripts at the same time by clicking a single arrow.  I have each arrow tagged with the script referencing the appropriate tag, but it is still executing both simultaneously. Id this a raycast issue?  I added a pic to the original post so you can see my layout.

Comment: Yep. I just debugged my raycast and for some reason it is triggering both arrows simultaneously, no matter which I arrow I click on.

Comment: well in your code you don't differ between which object your are hitting ... maybe instead of `Update` your should rather put your code into `OnMouseDown` for example. `OnMouseDown` is only called on the object the mouse is actually over

Comment: Ahh, didn't see your post. Ill give that a go.